# CSS - margin and padding dont work on positioning vertical

Tags: html, css

i am making something like this:

[image]

It looks like:
[image]

As you can see there, some things are bad positioned, i try to use padding margin to fix that but its not moving verticaly, how can i fix it?

My HTML:

```
    <div class='article-container'>
      <div class='article'>  
        <div class="img-position">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://funedit.com/andurit/try1/images/foto.png"/></a> 
        </div>
        <span class="topic-name"><a href="#">Název topicu nebo článku </a></span>
        <span class="date">28.8.2014 / 19:30</span>
        <span class="author"> od<a href="#"> Dwandy </a></span>
        <span class="article-description"> Ahoj jak se máte já se mám dobře ale nevím jak vy teda se máte? </span>
        <span class="article-comments"> <a href="#"> 4x reakce </a></span>
        <a href="#"><span class="read-article"></span></a> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

My CSS:

```
div.article-container {
    width:987px;
}

div.article {
    width:326px;
    height: 145px;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.img-position {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
}

span.author a{
    color:#555555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
span.topic-name{
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

span.topic-name a{
    color:#666666;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

span.article-description{
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 325px;
    display: block;
}

span.article-comments{
    margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
    float:left;
}

span.read-article{
    background-image: url("images/readit.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:block;
    width: 63px;
    height: 26px;
    float:right;
    margin: 18px 0px 50px 0px;
}

span.article-comments a{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#2d79bd;    
}

span.date {
    color:#a5a5a5;
}
```

Is here anybody who can help me to fix it to looks like on image?
Live preview can be found on: http://funedit.com/andurit/try1/

Thanks for reading this topic.

Comment: use list. `<ul>` is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative;` or `absolute` and use `top  left`

Comment: Yea i know its possibl with this kind of positioning but i dont ant to do it like that

Answer (score 0):

try giving :

```
.topic-name { float:left; margin:5px 0 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
span.topic-name{
     display: block;
}
```

And this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Margin does not work on inline elements. If you wish to apply margin to span, you'll either need to make that element block or inline-block.

Hence,

```
span.topic-name{
    display: block; 
        /* or */
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

will help you to apply margin to your elements and thus will eventually help in vertically aligning them.